# Why is it said "Collaboration" realizes "Use case" rather than vice versa?

Tags: uml

I am studying UML. I have some confusion about realization and collaboration.

Consider the diagram  (I hope diagram is correct)

[image: UML diagram for collaboration]

"Make a call" is a collaboration. "connect to destination" is a use case.

According to the book and various resources, I read that we say "Make a call" realizes "Connect to destination".

But as far as I understand, Collaboration is a logical concept we use to group a repetitive pattern(as in design patterns). The use cases(which have their own diagrams) are the ones who implement them (indirectly, as use cases will eventually have an related class diagram. those classes must be implementing them).

So shouldn't we say that "Use cases" realize "collaboration"?

What am I getting wrong here?

---

The source of confusion is java, where we have interfaces, and classes which implement them. we say a class implements interface. Isn't realization same as implementation?

What adds to this confusion is collaboration diagram, which seems to have nothing to do with collaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you first have the use case. It roughly tells what the added value of the system is. And there's also a story how this value is achieved. Now you start thinking about how the system under consideration (SUC) an realize (hence the name) this use case. So you construct collaborations where you show how the class design working towards fulfillment of the single goals in use cases. You can have multiple collaborations to either show different aspects or variants of the SUC.

Regarding your diagram: you have dependencies from `Connect to destination` to two other use cases. That's not correct. Use cases represent individual added value the SUC brings to its actors. So they basically can not depend on each other. All use cases of the SUC represent the total added value. Often people try functional decomposition with use cases and add a lot of include/extend dependencies. That does not lead to meaningful use cases and you loose focus. That is, you don't show the added values but stray around technical possibilities.